# Log users visiting a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to track visitors from my organization to my Spreadsheet. I've been researching scripts that can do this and I finally seem to have one that allows to track edits. However, some of the people visiting my spreadsheet, won't make any edit. And I still want to retrieve their email address (or at least handle).

Seems like it would be a very simple script but I haven't found anything. Anyone know how we can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe an installable onOpen...not really sure.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Cooper. That's correct, but I also found the solution, will add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around, I found the solution. Here's the script:

```
function onOpen(e)
{ 
  try
  {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Action')
    .addItem('Add Data', 'addData')
    .addToUi()  

    var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Login Details");
    sheet.appendRow([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),new Date()]);

  }
  catch(e)
  {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar as a debugging script as some people were able to break things but not remember how.

You could tie this into mailapp for sending notifications, stackdriver for just viewing logs after the fact or just appending it to a different spread sheet.

Set containing script to trigger on onopen for triggers.

```
  var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

A interesting issue I found is gs scripts will only ever run if the user has edit permissions. So if you have given view or comment only access scripts will not run and log this.

Edit: sorry, wrote this out a couple hours ago and missed the submit button.